# Agilizar el tema

Tags: traducción

Frecuentemente me toca escribir correos pidiendo a la gente que me haga algo más rápido. Estoy seguro que el verbo que debo usar es 'agilizar'. Pero es un verbo que me cuesta utilizar.
Alguien me puede explicar como decir las siguientes frases en Castellano utilizando 'agilizar' (o un verbo alternativo si lo hay)

*"Is there anything I can do to help speed things up?"*

*"How can we get this done quickly?"*

*"If we make this change will it speed things up?"*

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: I know you're looking for how to use 'agilizar' in Spanish, but I thought this might be helpful to someone. I often relate 'agilizar' to 'expedite' in English, and they are used in many of the same contexts (especially office, government, and other formal settings). Agilizar el proceso --> expedite the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Agilizar el tema* es exacto, pero la vaguedad de *el tema* le da un aire informal.

Prueba con lo siguiente:

> ¿Puedo hacer algo para agilizar el proceso?
>
> ¿Como podríamos terminar esto rápidamente?
>
> ¿Haciendo este cambio aceleraríamos las cosas?

Comment: Gracias por contestar!
@fedorqui: Gracias también! Las dos respuestas me parecen bien, aceptare a esta porque es la que llegó primero..

Answer (score 2):

Possible suggestions:

> "¿Hay algo que pueda hacer para agilizar / acelerar las cosas?"
>
> "¿Cómo podemos conseguir que estos temas se terminen a la mayor brevedad?"
>
> "Si realizamos este cambio, ¿se agilizarán / acelerarán las cosas?"

As you can see, both `agilizar` and `acelerar` can be used. I agree with you that `agilizar` sounds better.